# Categories in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I would like to have a multi select field for my categories. How can i do that?

My code doesn't work:

```
    function getCategories () {
        var options = [];
        var categories = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category');
        categories.forEach((category) => {
            options.push({ value: category.id, label: category.name });
        });
    }

    <SelectControl
        multiple
        label={__('Select a Post')}
        help={__('Select a post to display as a banner.')}
        options={getCategories}
    />
```

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve by implementing this? When you say it doesn't work, what does it do instead? Your code looks incomplete, can you update your question to include the full code in its entirety for implementing this? Where are you hoping to put the control? Is it going in a panel? A custom sidebar? A block? It's not obvious where you've put the `SelectControl`, and the component references choosing posts not categories. Use the edit link under the tags to answer as many of those questions as possible. How are you intending to save the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich have to write

```
options={getCategories()}
```

that solved this problem.